# Clarification on socket.socket()

Tags: python

I am going through a book called "Violent Python" and there is a script that pulls FTP data using a socket module

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21)) 
>>> ans = s.recv(1024)
>>> print ans
```

Can some one explain the `s = socket.socket()` section?

`s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))` Is it like saying:

`socket.socket.(connect(("192.168.95.148",21)))`

Just confused about the `s` variable and why it needs to be stated twice?  I hope that makes sense and I'm sure this applies to more than just this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket()` is a function in the library `socket`, so when you `import socket` and need to use the `socket()` function, you reference it by `socket.socket()`.

Alternatively, you could do, `from socket import socket` and do `s = socket()`

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket),

> Create a new socket using the given address family, socket type and
>   protocol number. The address family should be AF_INET (the default),
>   AF_INET6 or AF_UNIX. The socket type should be SOCK_STREAM (the
>   default), SOCK_DGRAM or perhaps one of the other SOCK_ constants. The
>   protocol number is usually zero and may be omitted in that case.

When you do `s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))` it is equivalent to `socket.socket().connect(("192.168.95.148",21))`.

In your case it would make sense to assign `socket.socket()` to `s` as you're using it multiple times.

```
>>> s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21)) 
>>> ans = s.recv(1024)
>>> print ans
```

would necessarily be better than,

```
>>> socket.socket().connect(("192.168.95.148",21)) 
>>> ans = socket.socket().recv(1024)
>>> print ans
```

Since you're also learning programming and in this specific context, you might want to look at the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. I would also suggest you to go through the [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards for good coding practices.

Going one step further, if you're in doubt of what a function or statement is doing, you can use the `help` function.

Excerpt from `help(socket)`:

> DESCRIPTION
>       This module provides socket operations and some related functions.
>       On Unix, it supports IP (Internet Protocol) and Unix domain sockets.
>       On other systems, it only supports IP. Functions specific for a
>       socket are available as methods of the socket object.
>
> ```
> Functions:
>
> socket() -- create a new socket object
> socketpair() -- create a pair of new socket objects [*]
> fromfd() -- create a socket object from an open file descriptor [*]
> gethostname() -- return the current hostname
> gethostbyname() -- map a hostname to its IP number
> gethostbyaddr() -- map an IP number or hostname to DNS info
> getservbyname() -- map a service name and a protocol name to a port number
> getprotobyname() -- map a protocol name (e.g. 'tcp') to a number
> ntohs(), ntohl() -- convert 16, 32 bit int from network to host byte order
> htons(), htonl() -- convert 16, 32 bit int from host to network byte order
> inet_aton() -- convert IP addr string (123.45.67.89) to 32-bit packed format
> inet_ntoa() -- convert 32-bit packed format IP to string (123.45.67.89)
> ssl() -- secure socket layer support (only available if configured)
> socket.getdefaulttimeout() -- get the default timeout value
> socket.setdefaulttimeout() -- set the default timeout value
> create_connection() -- connects to an address, with an optional timeout and
>                        optional source address.
> ```

Excerpt from `help(socket.socket())`:

> |  socket([family[, type[, proto]]]) -> socket object
>    |  Open a socket of the given type.  The family argument specifies the
>    |  address family; it defaults to AF_INET.  The type argument specifies 
>    |  whether this is a stream (SOCK_STREAM, this is the default)
>    |  or datagram (SOCK_DGRAM) socket.  The protocol argument defaults to 0,
>    |  specifying the default protocol.  Keyword arguments are accepted.
>    |  A socket object represents one endpoint of a network connection.

---

In summary, we have understood that `socket()` is a function which creates a new socket object and this function is available in the `socket` library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Really helped, full of info!  I think this book is missing some key information on things as per your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python svn trunk socket.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/socket.py) file:

> Functions:
>
> socket() -- create a new socket object